# Check if specific product has been bought on success page

Tags: php, magento

On the success page after checkout (success.phtml), I'd like to run a script only if a certain product ID has been bought. Is this possible?

I'm using Magento 1.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to Success.phtml

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();

$sku = $ids = array();
foreach($items as $item){
  //$sku[] = $item->getSku();
  $p_ids[] = $item->getProductId();
}

$p_id = 16;
if(in_array($p_id, $p_ids)){
   //run script
}
```

Comment: I'm not very competent with PHP, so I apologize, but assuming my SKU is BE002, and the product ID is 16, what would the above code look like?

Comment: This worked, but one exception. Maybe it has to do with our version of Magento, but I had to change `$item->getId();` to `$item->getProductId();`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This sort of logic might work on success.phtml page.

$

```
  if($this->getOrderId()) { 
    $found      = false;
    $skuToFind = 'abc';
     $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
     $items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
    if($item->getSku() == $skuToFind) {
        $found = true; break;
    }
}
if($found) { echo "Product Found"; } else { echo "No Found"; }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Well, you only need to find the cart variables. I'm not sure the exact variables but echoing out the $_SESSION will show you where they are. Check out the following example code:

```
if(in_array('2324242', $_SESSION['product_ids'])
{//in this case 2324242 is the product ID you are looking for

//Require_once ('script');
//Or redirect to script.php

}
```